# jquery selector closest, unable to get it

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a html like below. I want to select the h3 closest to the span having text laptop

```
.
.
.
.
.
<div>
<div>
    <h3>
    <a href="https://example2.com">test1</a>
    </h3>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>
    <a href="https://example1.com">test3</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <span>......laptop is need .......</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>
    <a href="https://example3.com">test3</a>
    </h3>
    <span>......laptop in .......</span>
</div>
.
.
.
```

I am trying to select all the `h3` that are closest to the `span` having text `laptop`

I tried

```
$("span:contains('laptop')").closest("h3")
```

Comment: `closest()` does not mean *nearest*. It means *closest in the ancestor chain, including the element itself*.

Comment: so how to get if going from bottom to top, get the first occurence, even its a sibling and not an ancestor

Comment: There is no generic solution to this problem. In particular, you cannot match the `<h3>` from the `<span>` in the same way for your first and second `<span>` elements (because of the additional `<div>`).